# Need to write md5 sums to file in Ant Script

Tags: xml, ant, echo

I have an Ant script that runs on Hudson and builds a few projects.  At the end, it runs md5 on a few files and I want those sums written into a file I create earlier.  It is not writing to the file, and I'm not sure the way around that.  As of now it just has basically the way it would in a Windows command line (which works manually, just not in Ant/XML).  Here is what that part looks like for the most part:

```
<echo message="Running md5 on the 3 required files"/>
<exec executable="${md5}">
  <arg line="${Dist}\binaries\LP100CRC.enc &gt; ${md5_output}" />
</exec>
<exec executable="${md5}">
  <arg line="${Dist}\binaries\LP100_BootCRC.enc &gt;&gt; ${md5_output}" />
</exec>
<exec executable="${md5}">
  <arg line="${Dist}\binaries\LP100512k.bin &gt;&gt; ${md5_output}" />              
</exec>
```

It generates the md5sums just fine, so there is nothing wrong there, it just doesn't write it to the file as expected; it just shows them in the console.  I originally thought it was because I was using ">" instead of "gt;", but I did change that to no avail.  I know that there should be some way to echo file into it, but I can't get that to go in right either.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output redirection in the arg line of the exec task won't work that way.  What you're looking for is the "output" attribute (and the "append" attribute):

```
<echo message="Running md5 on the 3 required files"/>
<exec executable="${md5}" output="${md5_output}">
  <arg line="${Dist}\binaries\LP100CRC.enc" />
</exec>
<exec executable="${md5}" output="${md5_output}" append="true">
  <arg line="${Dist}\binaries\LP100_BootCRC.enc" />
</exec>
<exec executable="${md5}" output="${md5_output}" append="true">
  <arg line="${Dist}\binaries\LP100512k.bin" />              
</exec>
```

Comment: a minor nit:  use arg value instead of arg line.  "It is highly recommended to avoid the line version when possible. Ant will try to split the command line in a way similar to what a (Unix) shell would do, but may create something that is very different from what you expect under some circumstances." from https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg